# How can you access the last element in a list in ocaml

Tags: list, pattern-matching, ocaml

I know that when using ocaml pattern matching it is possible to use `h::t`
When using this the h with refer to the first element in a list and the t will refer to the rest of the list. Is it possible to use this same type of matching to get the last element in a list. So the t will refer to the last element and the h will refer to the rest of the list.

An example of code that this would be useful for is

```
let rec remove x y = match y with
  [] -> x
| h::t -> remove (remove_element x (get_last y)) h
;;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no pattern that matches against the end of a list. It's not an attractive structure in OCaml because it takes linear time to find the end of a list. OCaml pattern matching is supposed to be fast.

You can reverse your list and match the beginning of the reversed list. It's only a constant factor slower than finding the end of a list.

Comment: That worked perfectly I even had a reverse function already created. Thank you

Comment: A reverse function already exists in the standard library: `List.rev`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the last element then you can traverse the list recursively until you encounter this case: `| [x] -> x`

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers says, you have to traverse/reverse the list to access it.

Depending on the specific problem, you could consider to use another data structure.

OCaml's standard library provides `Queue`, which could be of interest to you:
http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Queue.html